# ansible multiple per-host output to file

Tags: ansible

I want to run an Ansible playbook on multiple hosts and register outputs to a variable. Now using this variable, I want to copy output to single file. The issue is that in the end there is output of only one host in the file. How can I add output of all the hosts in a file one after the other.  I don't want to use `serial = 1` as it slows down execution considerably if we have multiple hosts.

```
-

     hosts: all
      remote_user: cisco
      connection: local
      gather_facts: no

      vars_files:
      - group_vars/passwords.yml

      tasks:
      - name: Show command collection
        ntc_show_command:
          connection: ssh
          template_dir: /ntc-ansible/ntc-templates/templates
          platform: cisco_ios
          host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          username: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
          password: "{{ ansible_ssh_pass }}"
          command: "{{commands}}"
        register: result

      - local_action:
          copy content="{{result.response}}" dest='/home/user/show_cmd_ouput.txt'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result` variable will be registered as a fact on each host the task `ntc_show_command` was run, thus you should access the value through `hostvars` dictionary.

```
- local_action:
    module: copy
    content: "{{ groups['all'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'result') | map(attribute='response') | list }}"
    dest: /home/user/show_cmd_ouput.txt
  run_once: true
```

You also need `run_once` because the action would still be run as many times as hosts in the group.